# jQuery IF statement based on browser width and a div's height

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm useless when it comes to jQuery but I need to write an if statement and i'm unsure of the exact code that would get what I want. This is what i'd like in pseudocode:

If browser width is less than 1670px AND height of div.banner is less than 1253px then let  div.title AND div.social's parent be div.banner else let the parent of div.title and div.social be the body (or browser window)

I hope this makes sense and I'd appreciate any help you could give.

Answer (score 1):

$(window).width()   = browser width
$('div.banner').height() = height of div.banner

```
if($(window).width() < 1670 && $('div.banner').height() < 1253)
{
 //do first
}
else
{
 // do else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(window).width() < 1670 && $(".banner").height() < 1253)
{
    var bannerContent = $(".title").html() + $(".social").parent().html();
    $(".banner").html(bannerContent);
}
else
{
    var bodyContent = $(".title").parent().html();
    $("body").html(bodyContent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for  this @Thomas but it doesn't seem to work properly. I have placed it within a $(document).ready(function () {   .....   }); is this correct? Does it matter where in the code my .title and .social div's sit on page load?

Comment: Should be fine if you put it in the $(document).ready()-Function. Maybe you insert some alert commands to see the html which is put into the banner div or the body.

e.g.:
var bannerContent = $(".title").html() + $(".social").parent().html();
alert(bannerContent);