# how to make parallax responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am using the jQuery plugin plax: https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax

I have made my own example and would like it to be responsive. Right now the position is absolute on the moving elements in the css, but I need it to be relative, so I can make it responsive.

But i can't get it to work

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FfKgY/

I think the problem is with the css:

```
            #shell {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            margin: 100px auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 318px;
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 318px;
            z-index: 1;
          }

          #plax-logo {
            width: 136px;
            height: 70px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            left: 90px;
            z-index: 3;
            background:#099;
            }

          #plax-sphere-1 {
            width: 93px;
            height: 92px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 4;
            top: 189px;
            left: 191px;
            background: #3CC;
            }

            #plax-sphere-2 {
            width: 215px;
            height: 215px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 100px;
            left: 53px;
            background: #3C9;
            }

            #plax-sphere-3 {
            width: 93px;
            height: 92px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 35px;
            left: 32px;
            z-index: 1;
            background: #669;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

I added another css string

```
header img {
width:100%;
}
```

This did the trick

Answer (score 0):

first off the next time you want to make an responsive website it might be worth checking out [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) In my opinion it is the best responsive boilerplate around. Seeing that you already got a page going and probably dont want to start over again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617762/jquery-if-statement-based-on-browser-width-and-a-divs-height) is a link to another post on Stack-overflow that you might seem useful. Cheers, Marco

---

EDIT

---

```
if($(window).width() < 1670 && $(".banner").height() < 1253)
{
    var bannerContent = $(".title").html() + $(".social").parent().html();
    $(".banner").html(bannerContent);
}
else
{
    var bodyContent = $(".title").parent().html();
    $("body").html(bodyContent);
}
```

You could use this code for the entire page to shrink its content. As you can see: if window width =< 1670 then this, else if width=<1500 then this etc etc.

Comment: I know how to do responsive lay-outs. But I can't seem to get the parallax jQuery plugin, mentioned above, to work with a responsive lay-out.

I'm not that good with jQuery, hence my question in here, so I don't really know what to look for in the link from the other post on StackOverflow?

Comment: So you don't think it's possible to fix it with the css?

I will just try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: I think you should do this with css, if this (classname which is styled with css and has width) else if (classname1 which is styled the same but with different width) else if (classname2 etc etc) If this is to much hassle to do (which i think it is) consider foundation.

Comment: You dont actually have to use foundation btw but you can just take a look at the code as an example.

Comment: But will foundation scale down the divs, when they are set to `position: absolute;`

Comment: I am only known to the basics of jQuery, so I can't seem to get the code you posted to work

Comment: I also think that foundation looks like a lot of css. I have tried bootstrap which works fine, and seems to be similar to foundation, but contains a lot of css which, for me is unnecessary. I would like it stripped and simple, so I know what controls what.

Together with this parallax plugin, I don't think either of the responsive lay-outs will work.

Comment: I'm not telling you to actually USE foundation but you can look how it makes the items responsive and learn from that. I believe you only need like 3 items to make something responsive.

Comment: ok, but as mentioned, the reason why it isn't responsive, is because it has an `position: absolute;` so my hassle is, how to get around this and make this relative, responsive and ready to use.

Foundation and all the other fluid grids, uses relative position and percentage

Comment: No foundation still works with position: absolute; you just have to style it correctly.

Comment: okay, I will try that, then... I will let you know how it goes